# Drupal form prepopulate from api

Tags: drupal-7

I want a drupal form which has a dropdown field called appointment time. I would like this field to be prepopulated from an external api call. What approach should I take?
Custom module/Webform?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a function called [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7). I think you can use that inside a hook in a custom module and then populate your field.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand using `hook_form_alter` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`. Inside those hooks you can get to your filter and modify the options of your select. An exemple would be :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'my_form_id'){
      $my_options = array('key' => 'value');
      $form['my_field']['#options'] = $my_options;
   }

}
```

So instead of defining the values of the array $my_options you can get the results from your external API et put them in the options of your select field.